# Remove a pattern if does not contains a specific words

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to remove everything from the given text after a specific pattern if doesn't include specific words. For example, I need to remove everything after a number if doesn't include "key1" and "key2"

```
txt1 = "this is a number 123456789 and there aren't any keys here. we might have a lot of words here as well but no key words'
```

There are no key1 and key2 in this text, so, the output for txt1 should be:

```
out1 = "this is a number"
```

```
txt2 = "this is a number 123456789 but we have their key1 here. key2 might be in the second or the third sentence. hence we can't remove everything after the given number'
```

There are key1 and key2 in the above text, so, the output for txt2 should be:

```
out2 = "this is a number 123456789 but we have their key1 here. key2 might be in the second or the third sentence. hence we can't remove everything after the given number'
```

I tried to use negative lookahead as below but it didn't work.

```
re.sub(r'\d+.*(?!key1|key2).*', '', txt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=^(?:(?!key[12]).)*$)^.*(?=\s\d+)
```

##### Short Explanation

- `(?=^(?:(?!key[12]).)*$)` Assert that the string does not contain neither `key1` or `key2`
- `^.*?(?=\s\d+)` Capture the string till the digits

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xWEgdR/2)

##### Python Example

```py
import re

strings = [
    "this is a number 123456789 and there aren't any keys here. we might have a lot of words here as well but no key words",
    "this is a number 123456789 but we have their key1 here. key2 might be in the second or the third sentence. hence we can't remove everything after the given number",
]

for string in strings:
    match = re.search(r"(?=^(?:(?!key[12]).)*$)^.*?(?=\s\d+)", string)
    output = match.group() if match else string
    print(output)
```